# If polynomial system is zero-dimension, when is iterated system likewise so?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, polynomials

Consider the square polynomial system $F(X)=0$ for  $F=\{f_1,f_2,\cdots,f_n\}\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ of some degree $k$ in $X=\{x_1,x_2\cdots,x_n\}$ with random coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$.

If the Ideal of this system is zero-dimension, under what condition is the Ideal of the iterated system:

$$
F^{((n))}=\underbrace{F(F(F(\cdots F))\cdots)}_{\text{n times}}=0
$$

likewise so?

Consider the following example:
$$
F(z,w)=\{-1-1/5 w+z^2,z\}
$$
so that $F^{((1))}=F.$
Then:
$$
F^{((2))}=F(-1-1/5w+z^2,z)=\left\{\left(-\frac{w}{5}+z^2-1\right)^2-\frac{z}{5}-1,-\frac{w}{5}+z^2-1\right\}
$$
and $F^{((3))}=F(F^{((2))})$.

$F^{((n))}$ can be computed in Mathematica with the following code:

```
In[42]:=  g0[{z_, w_}] = -1 - 1/5 w + z^2;
h0[{z_, w_}] = z;
vectorF[{z_, w_}] = {g0[{z, w}], h0[{z, w}]};
iterF[n_] := Nest[vectorF, {z, w}, n]
iterF[2]

Out[46]= {-1 - z/5 + (-1 - w/5 + z^2)^2, -1 - w/5 + z^2}
```

Comment: How do you compute the n-fold composition? You insert F at every argument? Can you give a 2-variable example of your question perhaps?

Comment: Added and example.  Can include Mathematica code to compute Ideal dimension (for small systems) if readers are interested.

Comment: For what it's worth if you're interested in looking up references, what you call a *square polynomial system* is usually called an *$n$-dimensional dynamical system* $\mathbb A^n_{\mathbb Q}\to\mathbb A^n_{\mathbb Q}$. The $\mathbb Q$ subscript indicates that the polynomials have coefficients in $\mathbb Q$.  I assume  "zero dimensional ideal" means geometrically zero-dimensoional, i.e., there are only finitely many points in $\mathbb C^n$ that are roots. Finally, if you homogenize and look at $\mathbb P^n\to\mathbb P^n$, then the properties of this rational map will be very relevant.